# over-plot dataframes with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a few dataframes to plot, do I need to aggregate them before initializing something like JointGrid or can I access the axis ala matplotlib's ax.plot() style?

Comment: give some example code or data and explain your requirement to make the user understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interest of using Seaborn is that the axes generated are data-aware, i.e. it inspects the full dataset, and creates Facets and plot properties that are linked to the properties of your data.

You could technically access each subplot and plot your individual dataframes in each of them, but you would lose the main interests of Seaborn : abilities to have common x and y axes across Facets, edit the legends and colors, etc. So I'd recommend concatenation of your Dataframes in a new one.

Edit: The number of Facets created also depends on your data, so definitely aggregate them together. For instance, if your df1 has only two levels for the variable "Country", and you ask Seaborn to generate a FacetGrid with the argument column="Country", then you will only get two columns, which might be a issue if you have a third level of "Country" in your second DataFrame df2.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling digging into the API that I was missing something in the philosophy.

Comment: No problem, glad I could help. Seaborn is a great library, and its doc is one of the most readable and well-written out there!